# Requests in vs code has a wrong caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")

Tags: python, https, openssl

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thanks!
I want to crawl https through the vs code, but when I run the code, it has a wrong.(It works fine in the jupyter notebook, and my python was Installed in E:/)

```
import requests

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
res = requests.get(url)

requests.exceptions.SSLError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

Comment: I have this same issue... It's OK when testing requests in cmd, but fails in vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ssl` module wasn't installed with the version of Python you're using with VS Code, so `requests` isn't able to make HTTPS connections. Either try another version of Python in VS Code that has the `ssl` module installed or see if you can re-install Python with `ssl`.